# Proof that $C([0,1])$ has uncountable dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Consider the space $C([0,1])$ of real valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$.

What are elementary arguments showing that the dimension of $C([0,1])$ as a real vector space is uncountable?

I look for an argument that could be understood by a first year student. So I don't want to use for instance the Baire category theorem establishing that every infinite dimensional Banach space has uncountable dimension or some Hilbert space methods.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{x-a}$ for $a>1$ are linearly independent.

If $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{c_i}{x-a_i}=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, the argument can be finished in different ways,

(1) $f(x)$ is analytic outside $a_i$, so it has isolated zeroes unless  $f(x)\equiv 0$, but if $c_i\not=0$, when $x\rightarrow a_i$, $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$, so $f(x)$ is not identically $0$.

(2) Multiply $\prod_{i}(x-a_i)$ on both sides, we get a polynomial $p(x)$ that vanishes on $[0,1]$, so it must be the zero polynomial for othwerwise it has at most finitely many zeroes. And if $c_i\not=0$, then let $x = a_i$, we have $p(a_i)= c_i\prod_{j\not=i}(a_i-a_j)\not=0$.

Comment: I suggest you post the answer to the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2902133/explicit-uncountable-linearly-independent-set-in-c0-1).